# How does one override print.css (Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 5.36.x)

Tags: css, drupal-7

This is referencing a Drupal 7 website with CiviCRM 5.36.x

When CiviCRM prints from a modal it invokes print.css which lives in /sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/. It does not invoke any other theme level css or the custom css that can be set in Administer/System Settings/Resource URLs.

In the case I'm working on, I have attached custom fieldsets to my membership types and applicants can apply via a webform to include a great deal of data.

If I view a membership from a contact record and print, the OEM print.css is invoked and the printed result or PDF is useless. To overcome this shortcoming, I've modified print.css but I'm looking for a long-term sustainable solution.

How does one override print.css with custom css?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're asking but if you turn off popups at Administer -  Customize - Display Prefs then that would get around it?

Comment: Are your changes to print.css useful to others?  How about creating a PR? Looks like that file has not had any attention for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [addStyle or addStyleUrl or addStyleFile methods](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/#css-stylesheets)

eg:

```
function extensionname_civicrm_config(&$config) {
  if (!empty($_REQUEST['snippet']) && $_REQUEST['snippet'] == 2) {
    Civi::resources()->addStyle('.label {     
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
    }');
  }
}
```